# Error saying the launcher activity is not found

Tags: android

It says that my launcher activity is not found when I have clearly put a launcher in the the manifest for some reason not defined though it does not launch it.

```
public class SplashLaunch extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashlaunch);
        final Main d = new Main(this);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setContentView(d);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

}
```

And here is the manifest file. In here you can see the activity .LAUNCHER, but for some reason it is not hitting this code or something?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Tripps.thesimplegame"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashLaunch"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASHLAUNCH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".YouFailed"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.YOUFAILED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using those actions for the filter?

Use:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You use an incorrect action `android.intent.action.SPLASHLAUNCH`.

Change from this;

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashLaunch"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASHLAUNCH" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

to this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashLaunch"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: this won't opent the .Main class

Comment: You need to specify the action `android.intent.action.MAIN` when you use the category `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`. Otherwise the icon of your app won't be listed in the application launcher